# Validate a date - asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to validate a date of birth field. I have

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Invalid date")]
[DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

It does absolutely nothing on the client side (no error message is displayed for invalid date). It shows an error message when the field is empty (the [Required] part). All other fields validate and display errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use the Date Validator from [DataAnnotations Extension](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/Date/Create)? It does exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create your own attribute, there is nothing built in that will handle it. The `DataTypeAttribute` will just check if it can convert the value from whatever the user entered to a `DateTime`.

```
public class PreviousDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object o)
    {
        rerturn ((DateTime)o < DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Is a sample, you'll need to build on it a little.